# Laravel ErrorException after install in AWS

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently I made an account in AWS. I'm using their EC2 with Ubuntu. I installed my Laravel project and in the command-line wrote `chmod -R 777 storage`. Now i'm getting an error:

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/BlueDrive/bluedrive/drive/bootstrap/cache/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied

What should I do to prevent this exception?

Comment: Check if /storage/framework/ has folders cache, sessions, views

Answer (score 1):

This is an access permission problem.

Run the following command:

```
   $ sudo chown nobody /var/www/html/BlueDrive/bluedrive/drive/bootstrap/

   $ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/BlueDrive/bluedrive/drive/bootstrap/
```

**OR**

run

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/the/folder
```

Comment: Actually after running this the hole page disappeared

Comment: chown the folder and try again?

Comment: If I type `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/BlueDrive/bluedrive/drive/storage` Everything works. No idea why

Comment: when you did the command initially, it was a relative directory. Here, you actually specified the exact path. That's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

go to the root of your project and

cd into the bootstrap directory. and issue chmod -R 777 .

Remember the storage directory is different from the bootstrap directory.

Laravel create a file name services.json inside boostrap/cache to list all your service providers in your application. laravel will need permission to do so that is why you are seeing that error.